# What "[[eosio::contract("somecontract")]]" means in eos code?

Tags: eosio-code

For example, in the contract "[eosio.token.hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/eosio.token/include/eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp)", in the line 20:

`class [[eosio::contract("eosio.token")]] token : public contract {`

Is that a special grammar defined in eos.io? What does it mean?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The double square bracket in c++ indicates [attribute specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

The `eosio::contract` in this case guides `eosio-cpp` [compiler](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt) to locate the smart contract class and make use of it when generating abi file with `--abigen` flag.